# Adding parametricplot3d in only z axis

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I am trying to add this parametric plot only in the z-axis (right now when I add it expands in the x,y, and z), the effect of this summation would be addition of amplitudes of the sine waves. Here is what I have now.  https://i.stack.imgur.com/PTcft.jpg

Here is the code I am using to implement it:

```
frequency = 1000;
speed = 13397.2441;
wavelength = speed/frequency;
s = (r - 2);
t = (r - 4);
u = (r - 6);
v = (r - 8); 
ParametricPlot3D[{{r*Cos[q] - 4, r*Sin[q], Sin[(2*Pi)/wavelength*(r)]},
  {s*Cos[q] - 2, s*Sin[q], Sin[(2*Pi)/wavelength*(s + wavelength/4 - 1)]},
  {t*Cos[q], t*Sin[q], Sin[(2*Pi)/wavelength*(t + wavelength/4 + 0.5)]},
  {u*Cos[q] + 2, u*Sin[q], Sin[(2*Pi)/wavelength*(u + wavelength/4 + 1.65)]},
  {v*Cos[q] + 4, v*Sin[q],  Sin[(2*Pi)/wavelength*(v + wavelength/4 + 3.5)]}},
  {r, 0, 25}, {q, 0, Pi}, PlotPoints -> 30, Mesh -> 20, PlotRange -> {{-25, 25}, {0, 35}, {-6, 6}}]
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What are `x,y` corresponding to the sum of `z`s ?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your question, but right now the graph plots 5 distinct waves.I would like the z's to be summed up at each node (for example the point (0,2)) irrespective of what x and y are. Does that make sense?

Comment: Can't you reparametrize your 5 waves in terms of common `x, y` ?

Comment: Yes, I've tried making 5 waves with the same z-component (which is a summation of all of the z-components now), but it returns the same graphic just with a larger amplitude. Maybe you could explain exactly what you mean by modifying the code I posted above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately I could not find an answer for this, so I ended up just simulating in MATLAB instead by generating all values over the field (in a matrix) and then summing as I was trying to do here.